# How do I fix this sudo permission issue - UID 503, should be 0 - El Capitan

Tags: macos, sudo

Whenever I try any `sudo` command whatsoever in terminal, I get the following error message:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 503, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I have tried logging into single user mode and typing in the following commands:

```
mount -uw

chown /private/etc/sudoers 0
```

After typing in the chown ownership line, I get an error message saying “illegal username”.

Other things I have tried:

- Reinstalling the OS X (El Capitan)
- Disabling System Integrity Protection (SIP).
- Calling Apple Care who say that `sudo` commands have been disabled in El Capitan.
- Logging in under Single User mode and typing in the following code:
  `chown root:wheel /private/etc/sudoers` This produced the error message “Operation Not Permitted” in my Standard, Admin, and Root accounts.
  The error message “Read-Only File System” came up when I logged in in Single User Mode.

FYI

When I run `ls -la /private/etc/sudoers` in Terminal, I get the following:

```
-rw-r-----@ 1 MY-ADMIN-USERNAME staff 67 18 Feb 14:03 /private/etc/sudoers
```

Note I’ve replaced my actual admin username with “MY-ADMIN-USERNAME” just so you know what’s showing.

I need `sudo` commands to work for a range of reasons, one of which is to get CrashPlan to work.

My hardware is a 2010 iMac, 3.2GHZ, 16GB Ram and 500GB SSD which was installed about a year ago.

These problems have only come up with El Capitan. I didn’t have them in the past with Yosemite.

Looking around online, I can see the many people have had similar issues but the resolutions unfortunately have not worked for me.

Comment: `chown /private/etc/sudoers 0` should be `chown root /private/etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to repair your sudoers file from Recovery Mode:

- Boot to Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting.
- Open Terminal from the menubar -> Utilities
- Enter `cd "/Volumes/main_volume_name/private/etc"`. Replace `main_volume_name` by the real main volume's name (check `diskutil list`), keep any spaces and upper/lower case characters as they are. If you use quotation marks like in the command here you don't have to escape spaces with a `\`
- Enter `chmod 440 sudoers`
- Enter `chown root:wheel sudoers`
- Check the file with `cat sudoers`. The default *sudoers* file should look like this:

  ```
  ## sudoers file.
  ##
  ## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
  ## Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
  ## that prevent sudo from running.
  ##
  ## See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
  ##

  ##
  ## Host alias specification
  ##
  ## Groups of machines. These may include host names (optionally with wildcards),
  ## IP addresses, network numbers or netgroups.
  # Host_Alias    WEBSERVERS = www1, www2, www3

  ##
  ## User alias specification
  ##
  ## Groups of users.  These may consist of user names, uids, Unix groups,
  ## or netgroups.
  # User_Alias    ADMINS = millert, dowdy, mikef

  ##
  ## Cmnd alias specification
  ##
  ## Groups of commands.  Often used to group related commands together.
  # Cmnd_Alias    PROCESSES = /usr/bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/renice, \
  #               /usr/bin/pkill, /usr/bin/top

  ##
  ## Defaults specification
  ##

  Defaults    env_reset
  Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
  Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
  Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
  Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
  Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
  Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

  Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

  ##
  ## Runas alias specification
  ##

  ##
  ## User privilege specification
  ##
  root ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

  ## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
  # %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

  ## Same thing without a password
  # %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

  ## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
  # %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

  ## Uncomment to allow any user to run sudo if they know the password
  ## of the user they are running the command as (root by default).
  # Defaults targetpw  # Ask for the password of the target user
  # ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL  # WARNING: only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'

  ## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
  ## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
  #includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
  ```

  Since your sudoers file is very small (67 bytes) you are probably missing some or all content. You may have to add/replace at least the lines without a prepending "#":

  ```
  Defaults    env_reset
  Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
  Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
  Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
  Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
  Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
  Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

  Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"
  ```

  and

  ```
  root ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```

  with:

  ```
  /Volumes/main_volume_name/usr/bin/nano /Volumes/main_volume_name/private/etc/sudoers
  ```

  The file should finally contain at least the following content:

  ```
  Defaults    env_reset
  Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
  Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
  Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
  Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
  Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
  Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
  Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
  Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

  Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

  root ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ​
  ```

  The file requires a trailing empty line! (Please don't simply copy the above because the last line here doesn't contain a new line but a zero-width space)
- Boot to your main volume and log-in as an admin
- Enter `sudo xattr -c /etc/sudoers` to remove the (false) attributes.
- Restore the complete *sudoers* file with `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` by editing in the above default *sudoers'* content
- Finally the file info should reveal the following:

  ```
  host:~ adminuser$ ls -laO /etc/sudoers
  -r--r-----  1 root  wheel  compressed 2299 31 Jul  2015 /etc/sudoers
  ```

  It hasn't to be compressed though and the date will obviously be different.

Comment: When I enter the code you suggested in recovery mode, I get the message: " /Volumes/main_volumes_name/private/etc: No such file or directory"

Comment: @ Klanomath - My main volume is called "Macintosh SSD" and after I enter the code, I get the following error message - "/Volumes/macintoshssd/private/etc: No such file or directory" I have also tried variations putting a space between the macintosh and ssd and using an underscore between them, and I get the same error message.

Comment: Thanks. So the code has now been accepted, however when I type "Cat Sudoers", the only thing that comes back is "2" on the following line and no other text.

Comment: I have: rebooted into an admin account and typed in the nano command which brought up a GNU nano app within terminal,  I copied and pasted the default content you provided within the terminal app, copied and pasted the additional root and %admin commands you provided at the end. Next I clicked control + x to get out and then got the save prompt “Save modified buffer” and I clicked for Yes. After pressing enter to confirm, I got an error message saying [ Error writing /Volumes/Macintosh SSD/private/etc/sudoers: Permission denied ]

Comment: I have also tried the sudo command: "sudo xattr -c etc/sudoers" and got the following error message.

>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Comment: @W.Sun then enable root (/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Uitlity), log in as root and edit the file manually.

Comment: It now works. Thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate your patience. I’d tried many things and all but lost hope. Now it’s all in order thanks to you.

Comment: I just found it after messaging you. Thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.